# C# MVC SessionExpireAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm facing a problem when the session expires and the users attempts to submit a form. Maybe I'm not using the Session expire properly but instead of redirecting the user back to the index, the system throws an error.

This is my definition of the SessionExpireAttribute

```
 public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "Index");
                redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where the attribute is placed in my class

```
namespace ContractManager.Controllers
{
[SessionExpireAttribute]
public class ICAController : Controller{}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: The error is : object not set to an instance of an object  (sorry I don't have the stack trace). Instead of catching that the session has expired, the code saving the form is executed and throws this error because the session has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to attach 'Attribute' postfix when assigning a custom attribute to a controller.

```
namespace ContractManager.Controllers
{
[SessionExpire]
public class ICAController : Controller{}
}
```

This will work. You create/extend attribute definition by postfixing 'Attribute' to the name of the attribute, the same way you have done at the top. But while assigning attribute to a controller or action mehod, strip the 'Attribute' part.